# How to keep unused results for microbenchmarking in MSVC, like gcc's asm volatile("" : : "g"(ptr) : "memory")?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I want to use [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) on a simple case test how a function performs on an array of data (for simplicity lets say its a sinus function):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

static void escape(void * p) {
    asm volatile("" : : "g"(p) : "memory"); 
}

static void BM_sin_default(benchmark::State& state) {
  while (state.KeepRunning()) {
    state.PauseTiming();
    int data_size = state.range_x()
    double lower_bound = 0;
    double upper_bound = 1;
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 engine(device());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(lower_bound,upper_bound);
    auto generator = std::bind(distribution, engine);
    std::vector<double> data(data_size);
    generate(begin(data), end(data), generator);
    state.ResumeTiming();
    for(auto & e : data) {    
        e = sin(e);
    }
    escape(&data);
}
BENCHMARK(BM_sin_default)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(8, 8<<20);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

The `escape` function will prevent the compiler from optimizing away the code that writes it, as presented in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk).

MSVC doesn't support inline assembly for x64, and even if it did it's not obvious how to port that.

What would be an MSVC x64 analog for GNU C `asm volatile("" : : "g"(p) : "memory");`?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: MSVC's inline-asm is so different and optimizer-defeating that it might not work well to use it that way anyway, even it was available (like in 32bit).  MSVC looks inside your asm statements to see which variables you use, but GNU C only looks at the constraints to optimize around an asm statement.

Comment: So one can not do benchmark's related to collections at all on MSVC? (because otherwize optemizer shall simply remove `e = sin(e);` loop as set only)

Comment: I don't use MSVC at all.  I have no idea what the answer to your question might be.  Hopefully one exists that doesn't add any overhead other that stopping the optimizer from throwing away unused results.  Storing a value to a `volatile` would work, but would compile to an actual store (and maybe an `mfence`, since doesn't MSVC give `volatile` semantics like a `std::atomic` variable, beyond the usual ISO C++ meaning?

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that in Microsoft C++ that wouldn't generate code as a side effect. It would be better if you rewrote it to do something with the code so it can't optimize it away. Say `f += sin(e);` and print the result.

Comment: Do you need to use MSVC?  AFAIK, it's not the best optimizing compiler.  Obviously if you do need to use it, then measurement is going to be an important part of getting the best performance out of it, so this is definitely a good question.